# Problem in getFirstHalf function on returning the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Working on a function that takes an array and returns the first half of that, but before returning , it calls itself until the length of the array is 1 :

```
const getFirstHalf = function (array) {
  const firstHalf = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.trunc(array.length / 2); i++) {
    firstHalf.push(array[i]);
  }
  if (firstHalf.length !== 1) {
    getFirstHalf(firstHalf);
  }
  return firstHalf;
};
```

Everything works as it is expected until it comes to return the result on that line the array gets the previous values until it is the first half of the first state of the array. I hope you get what i mean

For example :

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
console.log(getFirstHalf(numbers));
```

I expected to get [1] as the result but i get [1,2,3,4]

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? If you just want the first element, why not something simple as `array[0]` or `array.slice(0, 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result from the recursion:

Change

```js
getFirstHalf(firstHalf);
```

to

```js
return getFirstHalf(firstHalf);
```